# One single record instead of many?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Got a fairly simple question,

I have a few coldfusion pages, which each save data to my mySql database (phpMyadmin), however I want each time the website is ran through to save information all to the same record instead of creating a new record.

Im using post html method for data to go to the next page, but it does stay persistant onto the page after, so I cant save it all to the database at once in once cfquery statement.

Example :

Page 1: gets user details
Page 2: (stores the details from page 1)gets further user details
Page 3: (stores the details from page 2) etc

But stores in seperate records, whereas I want to store each session in the same record.

It saves these details in seperate records (as they are in seperate queries)
Any ideas?

Comment: Does your table a primary key defined? If so you can use it to update existing records. I prefer using auto_increment columns for defining primary keys.

Comment: Either use a session variable, or insert on the first page & pass the primary key to the subsequent pages for an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Ok, so I have an ID column thats set to autoincrement, so first pages inserts into DB, then I need to query the DB to get the ID(if this is right how?)? then pass this ID to each page then use UPDATE instead of insert?

Comment: You don't have to query for the ID if you store that ID for the active record in the session, url or form scope. The less times you go to the database the better.

Since you are using forms you can always store the ID in the form and pass it from page to page. Then you just need to run UPDATE statements: eg, 

update myTable set this='THAT' where id=#form.id#

Comment: Thanks, I tried using update on the second time Im going to the database, which worked but then when reloading the page it doesnt work due to 'duplicates', which means its still trying to insert into the previous record. How can I retrieve the ID, from the first Insert then pass this along in the forms?

Comment: You can retrieve the id from the first insert by adding: result="result" to your <cfquery> tag. The generated primary key will be availabe as the following variable #result.GENERATEDKEY#

Comment: Hi, I think that works fine, but now it comes up saying when I insert a new record: Duplicate entry 'num1' for key 'pd'. Dont know why?

Comment: Can you update you post to include some code? Specifically the pertinent query code.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting page 1, insert into the table and return the new ID.

On page 2, this ID needs to be made available. If you have it, you know which row needs updating when you submit page 2.

The same for page 3, 4, 5 etc.

Post code if you want a more specific answer.